# Microsoft.Web.WebJobs.Publish producing duplicate assemblies in deploy package

Tags: azure, msbuild, azure-webjobs, msdeploy, azure-webjobssdk

I have a large number of Azure WebJobs that all deploy to a single Azure App Service, along with a Website on the same Azure App Service. Each WebJob all use the WebJobs SDK and the Microsoft.Web.WebJobs.Publish nuget package (we are up-to-date with version 1.0.13) to package them up for deployment. The following are the MSBuild arguments we use in the CI build (VSTS) to produce the deploy package:

`/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=Release /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation=$(Build.StagingDirectory)`

This produces a package that works fine (in that the WebJobs run correctly as WebJobs) with the "Azure Web Service Deploy" VSTS task, that isn't the problem.

The problem is that the .zip file package duplicates all the WebJob assemblies. These duplicates end up making it out to the Azure App Service.

The folder structure in each WebJob package's .zip file is:

```
- Content/[build agent full path]/
     - app_data/jobs/continuous/[web job name]/[assembly files]
     - bin/[assembly files]
```

This causes a problem for 3 reasons:

1. We've started investigating partnering with a security vendor who will perform static analysis our our deployment packages. This duplication causes reporting issues.
2. Because the `bin/[assembly files]` makes it out to the App Service, they get inter-mixed with the assemblies for the Website that is also deployed to the same App Service.
3. Our build / release time is slowed down by transferring all this extra bloat in these deployment packages. My team practices Continuous Delivery and expects the pipeline to be *fast*.

So why does the Microsoft.Web.WebJobs.Publish package add in the `bin/[assembly files]` in addition to the required `app_data/jobs/continuous/[WebJobName]/[assembly files]`? And more importantly, how can I prevent the packaging process from including `bin/[assembly files]`?

I'd really hate to have to add build steps to piece apart the zipped packages and put it back together without the extra junk, or have to figure out a way to hand-craft the publish package. You have 1 job, Microsoft.Web.WebJobs.Publish! :)

Answer (score 3):

My update to https://stackoverflow.com/a/44611520/8654143

I had to add more than one override for existing targets to make it work:

```
<Target Name="CollectFilesFromContent" />
<Target Name="CollectFilesFromReference" />
<Target Name="CollectFilesFromIntermediateAssembly" />
<Target Name="CollectFilesFrom_SourceItemsToCopyToOutputDirectory" />
```

How to find it?

1) Run msbuild with `/verbosity:diag`

2) Inspect the log and look for `DestinationRelativePath=bin`; there will be related entry `FromTarget=SomeTargetName`

3) Add `<Target Name="SomeTargetName" />` to your `.csproj`

You should end with entries marked with `FromTarget=PublishWebJob`.

I think it is possible to filter contents of `FilesForPackagingFromProject` variable somehow (probably override `CustomCollectFiles` target and modify `FilesForPackagingFromProject` there) but I don't know msbuild good enough.

Comment: This worked for me!  I upgraded from the Microsoft.Web.WebJobs.Publish‌​.1.0.11 to Microsoft.Web.WebJobs.Publish‌​.1.1.0 and there was no fix.  So, I had to add `<Target Name="CollectFilesFromReference" />` and `<Target Name="CollectFilesFromIntermediateAssembly" />`.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to hear that you are running into this issue. As a temporary work-around you can override this target(CollectFilesFromIntermediateAssembly) in the csproj. This will stop the files from getting published to the bin folder.

Sample here:
https://github.com/vijayrkn/ASPNetPublishSamples/blob/master/WebJobFullFramework/WebJobFullFramework.csproj#L56-L57

We will fix this issue in the WebJobs.Publish NuGet package soon.

Comment: I am experimenting with this workaround now, but am resistant to marking it the answer if a permanent fix is forthcoming (would rather mark answer when someone tells me which official version of the package will fix this). Is there somewhere I can track this from the WebJobs.Publish team? I couldn't find a GitHub repo for the package...

Comment: UPDATE: Adding `<Target Name="CollectFilesFromIntermediateAssembly" />` to the .csproj files of the WebJobs seems to have made no difference to the output deployment package.

Comment: Please make sure that you are overriding this target after this line (https://github.com/vijayrkn/ASPNetPublishSamples/blob/master/WebJobFullFramework/WebJobFullFramework.csproj#L54). The target needs to be overridden after the webjob targets are imported. We are tracking this issue internally since we don't have a GitHub project for this. Will confirm the version number of the package once the fix is available.

Comment: Unfortunately, even when immediately after the `<Import Project="..\packages\Microsoft.Web.WebJobs.Publish.1.0.13\tools\webjobs.targets" Condition="Exists('..\packages\Microsoft.Web.WebJobs.Publish.1.0.13\tools\webjobs.targets')" />` it still includes the additional bin folder.

Comment: Can you please run the following command on WebJob project and share the output to vramak (at) Microsoft. This will help us diagnose the issue.
msbuild<proj.csproj> /p:PublishUrl="c:\temp\Output\" /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:Configuration=Release /p:WebPublishMethod=FileSystem /p:DeployTarget=WebPublish /v:diag

(sample:https://github.com/vijayrkn/ASPNetPublishSamples/blob/master/Publish.cmd#L68)

Comment: I sent you an email as requested. Title of email was same as this SO posting. The email was 24 MB with all the attachments (with the duplication, the build output is obviously quite large), so let me know if it doesn't go through.

Comment: @vijayrkn I'm experiencing the same issue so would be good to know when this is resolved