# MSBuilld copies unwanted files from Azure WebJob to another WebJob

Tags: azure, msbuild, webjob

We have 2 Azure Webjobs connected to our ASP WebApi application. None of them is using any dependencies from the other one. And yet, after publishing, one of them has executables from the other one. It's worth mantioning that this only happens on publish. Everything is normal on VS build.

This is how files hierachy looks like on Azure FTP

[image: FTP WebJobs file structure]

The first one, Deployment, is being published as expected. Those are executables in it's folder:

[image: Executables in Deployment WebJob]

The second one, EmailSender, has executables from the Deployment:

[image: Executables in EmailSender WebJob]

What's curious, there is also app.publish folder in both of them, containing only one and the same file `WebJob.Deployment.exe`:

[image: App.publish folder]

Deployment job works fine. Unfortunately Azure don't recognize EmailSender job, instead it executes Deployment. The only solution that works right now is to manualy delete Deployment's executables directly from FTP, on every publish.

Right now we tried couple of things from SO and blogs, but with no success.

- [Microsoft.Web.WebJobs.Publish producing duplicate assemblies in deploy package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44598052/microsoft-web-webjobs-publish-producing-duplicate-assemblies-in-deploy-package)
- [Azure Webjobs not getting updated after new publish](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues/1418)
- [GitHub solution](https://github.com/vijayrkn/ASPNetPublishSamples/blob/master/WebJobFullFramework/WebJobFullFramework.csproj#L56-L57)
- [Azure Web Job Run Command Incorrectly Set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52839343/azure-web-job-run-command-incorrectly-set)

**Edit:**
I did accomplished something. It did not resolve the problem, but we don't have `app.publish` folder anymore. [Here is the link to solution on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30142229/what-creates-the-directory-app-publish-in-visual-studio-2013). I don't know why we had 'ClickOnce security' options checked for `WebJob.Deployment` application.

**Update:**
I run few tests with `MSBuild` and found something curious. As I said before, `Visual Studio Publish` works just fine - no additional executables are deployed. But when I run `MSBuild`program (with the same `publish profile` and project configuration) I got additional `Deployment.exe` inside `EmailsSender` folder. This is the command I run:

```
MSBuild RestAPI.Host.csproj /t:Build /p:Configuration="Develop" /p:Platform="AnyCPU" /p:DocumentationFile="RestAPI.Host.XML" /p:DeployOnBuild="true" /p:PublishProfile="fakebuild_develop.pubxml" /p:OutputPath="backend\build\app\\" /p:SolutionDir="backend\\"
```

Can someone tell me what's the difference between `MSBuild` and `VS Publish`? I cannot find anything usefull on the internet.

Comment: Have you add reference of Deployment  to EmailSender? I add reference and get the `Deployment.exe` in EmailSender webjob. Also, I didn't see `app.publish` folder in them, could you show me more details about how to reproduce your problem? Here is a [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52839343/azure-web-job-run-command-incorrectly-set) issue you could refer to.

Comment: Nice, didn't find that SO question before. Unfortunately, like I wrote in question, I don't have references between WebJobs. I took a closer look at all of projects dependencies, and none of them reference any of WebJob, so there cannot be an indirect reference. I will try to put some more detailes today.

Comment: Also, you could try to create two new webjob to check if you could reproduce it. Hope to hear you good news.

Comment: I figured out what's that weird app.publish folder... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30142229/what-creates-the-directory-app-publish-in-visual-studio-2013

Comment: Glad to see that  you solve the problem by yourself.

Comment: I am not sure if the problem is solve, I'm testing it rght now. I just get rid of unused app.publish folder, but wrong executables might still be there

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work.It seems that problem was not connected to app.publish folder. Updating my question to provide more details.

Comment: @JoeyCai I added additional info to the question

Comment: The difference between them is that the MSBuild has its own configuration while the Visual Studio has more other information or configuration parameters offered based on MSBuild. So in the environment of VS, it will be generally more complicated. For more details, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/deployment/web-deployment-in-the-enterprise/understanding-the-project-file).